# if file == index.php

Tags: php, include, echo

I would just like to hear if it is possible to echo something on one page, and not every other page, even though they all get content from another file.

I have 3 pages, and they all have this in code:

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/index.php";
include_once($path);
?>
```

If I want "index.php" to echo something that "about.php" does not echo, can you then do it?
As the title says, I'd guess on something like this:

```
if filename == index.php then
echo=hello
```

Comment: look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],'index.php') !== false) {
  echo "do stuff";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't make it so specific If you add more and more pages what will you do? Handle them as special cases one by one? Now you have to handle two pages, after three months they'll be 10...and so on.

It's not a perfect solution but as starting point you may use a flag. Beginning like this:

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/index.php";
$helloWorld = TRUE;
include_once($path);
?>
```

And in your `index.php` include file:

```
if (helloWorld === TRUE) // or if (!!helloWorld)
    echo "Hello world";
```

Comment: might work, but the other solution i got was easier :)

Comment: This is a better solution than mine, but from my experience the amount of different page types rarely grow very large :)

Comment: @Mattis well I seldom see a web site with very few pages and what I don't like more is a bidirectional coupling of file names (index.php has to know another.php and another.php has to know index.php). Pages _may_ do not grow up quickly but file names may change, pages may be moved and so on. Anyway if OP has a _very_ controlled scenario and he is disciplined with code...faster can be better, why not?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti You are quite right. Personally I'm almost always dropping PHP in the front end entirely nowadays, just let it do the backend stuff and serve pages with js templates.